# System.Linq not found in app_code folder only

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013

I have a program I am writing in c# for the web and I am using Visual Studio 2013.  I right-clicked on my project and added the app_code folder.  Placed an existing piece of code in there from a different project.

The problem is that for some reason the "using System.Linq" says it's not found.  Even when I type in "using System." and look at the drop down, it's not in there.  I have the same include on some of my files on the root that work fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this a webforms project? If not, don't bother using the App_Code folder.

Comment: Is this C# or Visual Basic?  AFAIK C# has no "imports" statement.

Comment: Are you a java programmer? in c#, `import` is not used. try writing `using System` instead.

Comment: #1, sorry, I meant 'using'.  I'm sitting here working on something else in python.

#2, how can I tell if it is a Web Application Projects (WAPs)  or a Web Site Projects (WSPs)?

Comment: @MichaelPoznecki Why do you think you need an App_Code folder?  This is typically used to hold .cs files that are compiled at runtime.  `System.Linq` is a runtime assembly that should be available via the GAC and would never be put in the App_Code folder.

Comment: I have a .cs file in there.  It's called jobs.cs.  Inside that .cs file, I have "using System.Linq".

Comment: I also have other "using"s, but only this one has 'Linq' underlined in red as an error.